# Need to stop ex husband from getting into my desktop

Tags: internet-security

First, I’m VERY sorry if I am in the WRONG place here.  I know my way around computers, compared to all of you, probably NOT AT ALL!  I am in the middle of a divorce from a VERY abusive man who is LITERALLY genius when it comes to IT and setting up ports and using VPN’s, etc..He pirates/shares movies, uses NAS drives, etc..  He works for a VERY WELL KNOWN software company and knows everything about everything.  Which is the scary part.  My 4 children and I are currently living with my parents and my ex knows their IP address and their WiFi passwords, etc..  I have since changed the WiFi password, but he hacks EVERYTHING.  So, I am probably answering my own question, but ... can ANYONE PLEASE offer me advice as to HOW I can keep him OUT of my computer?

He told me that he was in one of my google accounts and found evidence and printed it that I searched for “how to hire someone to kill my husband”, and “if my husband dies while we are in the middle of a divorce, am I still entitled to his life insurance money”!!!!!!  One my children’s lives ... I NEVER, EVER, searched for this.  But it’s from my parents IP address!!!  And NO, my parents didn’t search for it either ... they barely know how to turn their computer on!  ;)

Any help, would be GREAT! 
Thank you in advance ...

Comment: I apologize about the “tag” it wouldn’t let me pick from ANY of the other tags ... ‍♀️

Comment: This is entirely inappropriate here. This is a criminsl matter, not something technical people with no knowledge of your setup can solve.

Comment: Hire a professional to wipe and reinstall the OS on all your computers you use.

Comment: If you know you nor your parents or anyone else has searched this, then you know he is fully of $%it. I call his bluff and say he is feeding you a lie. He knows you know he is an IT professional and is trying to scare you into thinking he has access, etc. Sniffing traffic and packets on the network would tell you what connections are established, etc. He's trying to scare you into resetting everything, buying new PC, etc. I'd have to agree to make a police report since he is a woman abuser POS in case you need that later and have a good IT pro check over your environment and advise otherwise.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT unfortunately it is entirely possible he has some kind of access to a device on that network and has caused such requests to be made.  According to https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001350.htm Google does record your Google search history - so this is all plausible.

Comment: Another thought - its a long shot - but are you able to find a copy of the Google history yourself, and look at the time those entries were created?  Then see if you have a strong alibi.  If so, take it all to the police and pressure them to investigate.

Answer (score 3):

I am reluctant to answer this question (as it's not possible to fully answer without knowledge of your setup we don't have) and only do so in part to steer you clear of well intentioned but bad advice.

The short answer is, of-course "you cant". Report the crime to the police and get a case number (which may protect you down the line).

You need to realize that once a system is compromised, you cant patch it back together unless you know exactly what has been done - which you don't.

If you have some funds, go get a new cellphone and number. Install a password manager on it. Do not share the number with friends or family, and make sure the carrier knows it's linked to you and no one else is entitled to ask for changes on the account.  You now have a secure platform from which to take back control.  (if you can't afford this, wipe your computer and install a password manager).

Get a new email address. Ideally, with a smaller local provider, and again make them aware of the risk of compromise/reset. In this way, you also have a record and more recourse then using something like Gmail.

The next step is to change all your passwords, and use the password manager to make sure they are unique - in this way if one is compromised it does not compromise multiple accounts.  Wherever possible, use 2FA, with the 2FA application being on your cellphone. Change your email as well.

You then go to each device and back up your documents, user data, and keys. Wipe the device and do a fresh reinstall of everything - don't move programs or configs.

You need to ensure you install and keep AV protection up to date. I'd recommends Malwarebytes or similar.

You also need to consider your WIFI network as if it were an open network - i.e., anything going through it should not be trusted, just like the rest of the Internet.

You probably cant stop access to the parts of the network/devices controlled by other family members. All you can do is distance yourself from them.